# Get target code using OBJDUMP

Tags: linux, objdump

How to annotate fragments of target code with the source statements that they correspond to using OBJDUMP in linux.

Comment: Was the object code compiled with debugging information (for gcc, the `-g` option)?

Comment: Compiled with  gcc -static -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables programname.c .